# jQuery .live() for multiple selectors - how to unbind event from one of them?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, live

I have this piece of code:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPgMWm

html:

```
<a href=# class=test1>test1</a>
<a href=# class=test2>test2</a>
```

and script:

```
$('.test1, .test2').live('click', dosth);

function dosth(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('test');
}

//my script
$('.test1').die('click');
$('.test1').unbind('click');
```

As you see, I have `.live()` on multiple selectors (legacy code :() and I have to unbind event from only one of selectors... How can I do that?

With new jQuery and `.on()`/`.off()` it works like a charm, but what if I cant switch to new version? I can't modify script with bindings...

EDIT:

I have 1.4.4 version. And I can't modify handler. Only "my script" part.

Comment: You could filter it out inside handler regarding event target and some condition: `if(someCondition && $(e.target).is('.test1')) return;`. An other solution is to bind click event on `.test1` and stopping propagation (instead of using die())

Comment: This is 1.4.4 version.

Comment: @kzg: I've removed the "as you can see in the codepen" -- first off, it doesn't add anything. Second, it doesn't matter that we could have seen it if we'd gone off-site, content for your question goes **in** your question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can. You'd have to unbind the old entirely, then rebind the ones you want to keep.

```js
$('.test1, .test2').live('click', dosth);
    
function dosth(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('test');
}
    
$('.test1, .test2').die('click');
$('.test1').live('click', dosth);
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<div class="test1">test1</div>
<div class="test2">test2</div>
```

(And needless to say, update to a recent version ASAP.)

Comment: I hope there is another way, because is a little bit dengerous - I dont know how other developers might change bindings part in the future :/ So I'm still looking for some solution...

Comment: @kzg: The best solution is, of course, to update to a recent version, since you said `.on`/`.off` works.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use the data attribute

```js
    function dosth(e) {
      if ($(this).data("clickme") == true) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('test');
      }
    }

$(function() {
    $('.test1, .test2').live('click', dosth);
    $('.test1').data('clickme',true);    
    $('.test2').data('clickme',false); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="test1">Click me</a><br/>
<a href="#" class="test2">Don't click me</a>
```

UPDATE - if you need to modify dosth, you can replace it:

```
var mydosth=dosth; 
dosth=function(e) { if (....) mydosth(e); }
```

Comment: I cant modify dosth() function :)

Comment: Of course you can. If you can change the live statements you can also do 
`mydosth=dosth; dosth=function(e) { if (....) mydosth(e); }`

Comment: Well! It might help:)